# Fio brandswitch measure

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, io, benchmark

In disk benchmarking tool fio there is statistics for brandswitch

```
Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=20.9MiB/s (21.9MB/s), 10.4MiB/s-10.8MiB/s (10.9MB/s-11.3MB/s), io=64.0MiB (67.1MB), run=2973-3069msec
```

According for docs:

```
Values outside of brackets are power-of-2 format and those within are the equivalent value in a power-of-10 format.
```

As far as I know 1 MB/s = 8MiB/s.
But here 20.9MiB/s complies to 21.9MB/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"1 MB/s = 8MiB/s" is not true. 1MiB is equal to 1.024MB, or 1 MB is ~ 0.9537 MiB.

Both are measurements of bytes.

One byte is certainly 8 *bits*, which is why it is also known as an *octet*. But none of these measurements reference bits. They are all bytes.